# Animate UIImageView lost center

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I'm having problem in iOS that I can't figure out.

I have an animation for an UIImageView that works great.
Also, I have a setCenter that put the UIImageView in the correct position on the screen that work great too.

The problem is when I try to set the center of the UIImageView and then start the animation, the animation works but the center don't change.

Animation code:

```
-(void)startMirror{

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed){}];
  }
```

Main code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 [self.face1 setCenter:CGPointMake(200, 300)];
 [self.face1 startMirror];
}
```

I made a mini project with my problem, you can download from here we.tl/0gPqkVDCKK 
Try comment and uncomment line 46 and you will see what my problem is.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I'm having a hard time understanding this question.

Comment: When I execute the "Main code", the animation start but the UIImageView center is not 200, 300.
Please tell me if now you understand the question. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any code related to the position of the view that you aren't showing? Because I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: The position of the view change a few times before start the animation. Always using setCenter.
 
I not sure if this is use full but I stop the animations using:
    [self.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

Comment: Main code runs when touchesBegan, I just updated the question.

Comment: Alright, and what is `currentAnimation`?

Comment: That should not be, sorry. (I have the animation inside an implementation of UIImageView, so I checked if setCenter inside the implementation works, but didn't work)

Comment: Are you creating `face1` in a xib, in a storyboard, or in code?

Comment: face1 is a UIImageView created in a xib

Comment: I made a mini project with my problem, you can download from here http://we.tl/0gPqkVDCKK Try comment and uncomment line 46 and you will see what my problem is.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to transform the center point after you do the transform in startMirror.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, replacing:

```
[self.face1 setCenter:CGPointMake(200, 300)];
```

with:

```
self.face1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-11, 80);
```

And in the animation

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, -1, 1);
```